# How to extend/reuse Python C Extensions/API implementation?

Tags: python, python-c-api

The problem is that now, I have to use the Posix C `getline` function to get the line from the file, only then convert it to a Python Unicode Object using `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` and cache it using my [caching policy](https://github.com/evandrocoan/fastfilepackage/blob/9d10d7852aee9f513563f624038fa38911a9ac73/source/fastfile.cpp#L118-L135) algorithm. This process is [losing 23%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56284547/4934640) of performance compared to Python builtin `for line in file` C implementation.

If I remove the `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` call from my code, then, my implementation using the Posix C `getline` becomes `5%` faster than the Python builtin `for line in file` C implementation. So, if I can just make Python directly give me a Python Unicode String object, instead of having to call the Posix C `getline` function first (only then convert its result to a Python Unicode Object), my code performance would improve almost by `20%` (from a maximum of `23%`), i.e., it will not become `100%` equivalent to `for line in file` performance because I am doing a little work by caching stuff, however this overhead is minimal.

For example, I would like to take the [_textiowrapper_readline()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_io/textio.c#L2014) function and use it in my code like this:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <textio.c.h> // C Python file defininig:
                      // _textiowrapper_readline(),
                      // CHECK_ATTACHED(),
                      // PyUnicode_READY(), etc

typedef struct
{
    PyObject_HEAD
}
PyMymoduleExtendingPython;

static PyObject* 
PyMymoduleExtendingPython_iternext(PyMymoduleExtendingPython* self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject *line;
    CHECK_ATTACHED(self);
    line = _textiowrapper_readline(self, -1); // <- function from `textio.c`

    if (line == NULL || PyUnicode_READY(line) == -1)
        return NULL;

    if (PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(line) == 0) {
        /* Reached EOF or would have blocked */
        Py_DECREF(line);
        Py_CLEAR(self->snapshot);
        self->telling = self->seekable;
        return NULL;
    }
```

```cpp
    return line;
}

// create my module
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_mymodule_extending_python_api(void)
{
    PyObject* mymodule;
    PyMymoduleExtendingPython.tp_iternext = 
           (iternextfunc) PyMymoduleExtendingPython_iternext;

    Py_INCREF( &PyMymoduleExtendingPython );
    PyModule_AddObject( mymodule, "FastFile", (PyObject*) &PyMymoduleExtendingPython );
    return mymodule;
}
```

How could I include the [textio](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_io/textio.c#L2014) implementation from C Python and reuse its code on my own Python C Extension/API?

As presented in my last question, [How to improve Python C Extensions file line reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260096/how-to-improve-python-c-extensions-file-line-reading), the Python builtin methods for reading lines are faster than writing my own with C or C++ standard methods to get lines from a file.

On [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56260851/4934640), it was suggested for me to reimplement the Python algorithm by reading chunks of 8KB and only then calling `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` to decode them, instead of calling `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` on every line I read.

However, instead of rewriting all C Python code already written/done/ready to read lines, I could just call its "getline" function `_textiowrapper_readline()` to directly get the line as a Python Unicode Object, then, cache it/use as I am already doing with the lines I get from Posix C `getline` function (and pass to `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8()` decode them into Python Unicode Objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to directly import the C API (Extensions) functions, but I used Python to import the `io` module, which has a link/reference to the global builtin function `open` as `io.open()`.

```cpp
bool hasfinished;
const char* filepath;
long long int linecount;
std::deque<PyObject*> linecache;

PyObject* iomodule;
PyObject* openfile;
PyObject* fileiterator;

FastFile(const char* filepath) : hasfinished(false), filepath(filepath), linecount(0) {
    iomodule = PyImport_ImportModule( "io" );

    if( iomodule == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FastFile failed to import the io module '"
                << filepath << "')!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
    PyObject* openfunction = PyObject_GetAttrString( iomodule, "open" );
```

```cpp
    if( openfunction == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FastFile failed get the io module open function '"
                << filepath << "')!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
    openfile = PyObject_CallFunction( openfunction, "s", filepath, 
            "s", "r", "i", -1, "s", "UTF8", "s", "replace" );

    PyObject* iterfunction = PyObject_GetAttrString( openfile, "__iter__" );
    Py_DECREF( openfunction );

    if( iterfunction == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FastFile failed get the io module iterator function '"
                << filepath << "')!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
    PyObject* openfileresult = PyObject_CallObject( iterfunction, NULL );
    Py_DECREF( iterfunction );
```

```cpp
    if( openfileresult == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FastFile failed get the io module iterator object '"
                << filepath << "')!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
    fileiterator = PyObject_GetAttrString( openfile, "__next__" );
    Py_DECREF( openfileresult );

    if( fileiterator == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FastFile failed get the io module iterator object '"
                << filepath << "')!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
}

~FastFile() {
    this->close();
    Py_XDECREF( iomodule );
    Py_XDECREF( openfile );
    Py_XDECREF( fileiterator );

    for( PyObject* pyobject : linecache ) {
        Py_DECREF( pyobject );
    }
}

void close() {
    PyObject* closefunction = PyObject_GetAttrString( openfile, "close" );
```

```cpp
    if( closefunction == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FastFile failed get the close file function for '"
                << filepath << "')!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
    PyObject* closefileresult = PyObject_CallObject( closefunction, NULL );
    Py_DECREF( closefunction );

    if( closefileresult == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FastFile failed close open file '"
                << filepath << "')!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
    Py_DECREF( closefileresult );
}

bool _getline() {
    // Fix StopIteration being raised multiple times because 
    // _getlines is called multiple times
    if( hasfinished ) { return false; }
    PyObject* readline = PyObject_CallObject( fileiterator, NULL );

    if( readline != NULL ) {
        linecount += 1;
        linecache.push_back( readline );
        return true;
    }

    // PyErr_Print();
    PyErr_Clear();
    hasfinished = true;
    return false;
}
```

When compiling this with `Visual Studio Compiler`, it has the following performance using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260096/how-to-improve-python-c-extensions-file-line-reading):

```py
print( 'fastfile_time %.2f%%, python_time %.2f%%' % ( 
        fastfile_time/python_time, python_time/fastfile_time ), flush=True )
```

```
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.985254
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.084283
fastfile_time 1.10%, python_time 0.91% = 0.09%
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.979861
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.073879
fastfile_time 1.10%, python_time 0.91% = 0.09%
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.990369
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.086416
fastfile_time 1.10%, python_time 0.91% = 0.09%
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.975223
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.077857
fastfile_time 1.11%, python_time 0.90% = 0.10%
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.988327
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.085866
fastfile_time 1.10%, python_time 0.91% = 0.09%
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.971848
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.087894
fastfile_time 1.12%, python_time 0.89% = 0.11%
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.968116
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.079976
fastfile_time 1.12%, python_time 0.90% = 0.10%
$ python3 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.980856
FastFile timedifference 0:00:01.068325
fastfile_time 1.09%, python_time 0.92% = 0.08%
```

But when compiling it with `g++`, it got this performance:

```
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.703964
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.813478
fastfile_time 1.16%, python_time 0.87% = 0.13%
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.703432
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.809531
fastfile_time 1.15%, python_time 0.87% = 0.13%
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.705319
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.814130
fastfile_time 1.15%, python_time 0.87% = 0.13%
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.711852
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.837132
fastfile_time 1.18%, python_time 0.85% = 0.15%
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.695033
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.800901
fastfile_time 1.15%, python_time 0.87% = 0.13%
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.694661
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.796754
fastfile_time 1.15%, python_time 0.87% = 0.13%
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.699377
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.816715
fastfile_time 1.17%, python_time 0.86% = 0.14%
$ /bin/python3.6 fastfileperformance.py
Python   timedifference 0:00:00.699229
FastFile timedifference 0:00:00.818774
fastfile_time 1.17%, python_time 0.85% = 0.15%
```