# How to use basic string operations with PyObject* strings?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I would not like to keep converting every Python String Object from `PyObject*` to `std::string` or `char*` with [PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8) and [PyUnicode_AsUTF8](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8) because it is an expensive operation.

On my last question [How to extend/reuse Python C Extensions/API implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286313/how-to-extend-reuse-python-c-extensions-api-implementation), I managed to use the Python `open` function, to directly give me a `PyObject*` string. Once doing that, it is very simple to send the string back to the Python program because I can just pass its `PyObject*` pointer back, instead of doing a full char-by-char copy as `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` or `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` do.

On the `regex` implementation of CPython API, I can find a function [like this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f0bfd27a5e3a9a7cbeb2ddd45ce50c3d4bdb4e9/Modules/_sre.c#L354-L391):

```cpp
static void* getstring(PyObject* string, Py_ssize_t* p_length,
          int* p_isbytes, int* p_charsize,
          Py_buffer *view)
{
    /* given a python object, return a data pointer, a length (in
       characters), and a character size.  return NULL if the object
       is not a string (or not compatible) */

    /* Unicode objects do not support the buffer API. So, get the data directly. */
    if (PyUnicode_Check(string)) {
        if (PyUnicode_READY(string) == -1)
            return NULL;
        *p_length = PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(string);
        *p_charsize = PyUnicode_KIND(string);
        *p_isbytes = 0;
        return PyUnicode_DATA(string);
    }

    /* get pointer to byte string buffer */
    if (PyObject_GetBuffer(string, view, PyBUF_SIMPLE) != 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "expected string or bytes-like object");
        return NULL;
    }
    *p_length = view->len;
    *p_charsize = 1;
    *p_isbytes = 1;

    if (view->buf == NULL) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Buffer is NULL");
        PyBuffer_Release(view);
        view->buf = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    return view->buf;
}
```

It does not seem to be using `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8` or `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` to work with the `PyObject*` coming from the Python Interpreter.

How can I use basic string operations with `PyObject*` strings without conversion then to `std::string` or `char*`?

I would call basic operations the following examples: (Just for exemplifying, I am using Py_BuildValue to build a `PyObject*` string from a string as a `char*` or `std::string`)

```cpp
static PyObject* PyFastFile_do_concatenation(PyFastFile* self)
{
    PyObject* hello = Py_BuildValue( "s", "Hello" );
    PyObject* word = Py_BuildValue( "s", "word" );

    // I am just guessing the `->value` property
    PyObject* hello_world = hello->value + word->value;
    hello_world; // return the `PyObject*` string `Hello word`
}

static PyObject* PyFastFile_do_substring(PyFastFile* self)
{
    PyObject* hello = Py_BuildValue( "s", "Hello word" );
    PyObject* hello_world = hello->value[5:];
    hello_world; // return the `PyObject*` string `word`
}

static PyObject* PyFastFile_do_contains(PyFastFile* self)
{
    PyObject* hello = Py_BuildValue( "s", "Hello word" );

    if( "word" in hello->value ) {
        Py_BuildValue( "p", true ); // return the `PyObject*` boolean `true`
    }
    Py_BuildValue( "p", false ); // return the `PyObject*` boolean `false`
}
```

Comment: Um… are you asking for a link to the `PyUnicode_*` API documentation?

Comment: The link is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html) but not many examples over there.

Comment: Why does it need examples? The relevant functions have pretty obvious names and behave in predictable ways. For example the concat function takes two `PyObject*` inputs and returns another `PyObject*` as output - what could be unclear about that?